# Can I include a free appexchange app along with my managed package?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

I am working on creating a managed packaged. Can I include free appexchange apps along with my managed package or other free components from the appexchange? There are 1 or 2 free apps that I think would be complementary to my managed package is my reasoning.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dependency on those items, but you can't directly include them in your package. You would want to include those dependencies in your application documentation, if necessary, since subscribers would have to install them before installing your own package.